# axios.all spread and catch all

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I'm using .all method of popular library 'axios' for handling my ajax requests.

But how can I handle errors in case all requests got 404?

for example:

```
axios.all([
        axios.get('http://some_url'),
        axios.get('http://another_url'),
      ])
        .then(axios.spread((someUrl, anotherUrl) => {
         // ... boring stuff goes there
        }))
        .catch(() => {
         //... error goes there
        });
```

[image]

So, seems only one error has ben "catched".

How can I catch them all? Or maybe there any kinda .finally?

Answer (score 11):

The problem (as you already know) is that you will get into `catch` block as soon as the first promise rejects, making it impossible to collect all failed responses in the same `catch`. However, you still can handle failed promises manually to aggregate errors and throw afterwards.

Check it this will work for you:

```
const promises = [
  axios.get('http://some_url'),
  axios.get('http://another_url'),
]
const promisesResolved = promises.map(promise => promise.catch(error => ({ error })))

function checkFailed (then) {
  return function (responses) {
    const someFailed = responses.some(response => response.error)

    if (someFailed) {
      throw responses
    }

    return then(responses)
  }
}

axios.all(promisesResolved)
  .then(checkFailed(([someUrl, anotherUrl]) => {
    console.log('SUCCESS', someUrl, anotherUrl)
  }))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('FAIL', err)
  });
```

You will get into `catch` block if at least one of the promises fails. You can find one which one by checking `err` array of responses.

Comment: Worked for me, but the code was not that intuitive for understanding. Can you add more explanation on what the `promisesResolved` and `checkFailed` are doing

Comment: @XavitojCheema You just need to handle situation when some requests fail. In this case you catch it and return `({ error })` from it, thus recovering from exception. So the idea is to make *all* requests pass (resolve), even if it fails. If something failed the error will be available as `error` property of the response object.

Comment: okay, that would have required more understanding of the behavior of the Promise when it fails. Thanks! for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible due to the fail fast behaviour of Promise.all. If any of your requests fail, they will automatically be the culprit and the result in the catch.

```
    Promise.all([
      Promise.reject(Error('1')),
      Promise.reject(Error('2')),
      Promise.reject(Error('3'))
    ]).then((results) => {
      console.log(results)
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error.message)
    })
```

This resulting code will always print 1 as it is the first to fail.I think a similar feature was requested on the repo and they said it wasn't possible.

I was going to leave this as a comment but don't have a high enough reputation yet.

Comment: Dude, everyone doing search before posting question. https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/76#issuecomment-233146010

Comment: Funnily enough I read that last week because i had the same question. Should have just posted the link.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @dfsq did not work for me because it throws all requests when one has an error. I changed his code so every request either gets resolved or throws an error. @dfsq please review this answer if the code is correct, since I built it on your solution.

```
const promises = [
  axios.get('http://some_url'),
  axios.get('http://another_url'),
]
const promisesResolved = promises.map(promise => promise.catch(error => ({ error })))

function checkFailed (then) {
    return function (responses) {
        responses.forEach(response => {
            if (response.error)
                throw response;
            return then(response);
        })
    }
}

axios.all(promisesResolved)
  .then(checkFailed(response => {
    console.log('SUCCESS', response)
  }))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('FAIL', err)
  });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @AlbertLogicEinstein it is written clearly plese do not spam. If you comment that it is unclear at least point to the part that you did not understand and I will try to explain it to you in simpler terms. Also my code is not "answer" to the OP's question just alternative upgrade to the correct answer. I came to the problem where I needed this functionality, so I shared it if anyone else would need it.